# D3 Transitionning data with sequences sunburst

Tags: d3.js, sunburst-diagram

### Introducing

I'm using Sequences Sunburst of d3.js for visualization of data.

I want to add a **transition between two datasets** (triggered by a button). I would like each arc to animate to display the new data.
Something like this: [(1)Sunburst_Exemple](http://strongriley.github.io/d3/ex/sunburst.html), but without changing the accessor.

---

### Research

In the (1)Sunburst_Example, the value accessor is modified. But I want to change the data, not the function that defines how to reach the data.

So, I searched a way for redefining data into *path*.

I was inspired by (2)Sunburst_Exemple, using *each()* method to store old values and *attrTween()* for transitions. But nothing is changing and I have the following error message: 
    **Maximum call stack size exceeded** . Maybe caused by the fact I have a method and I'm not in a global scope.
(2) link : _http://ninjapixel.io/StackOverflow/doughnutTransition.html

Then I have tried (3)Zoomable_Sunburst example, but nothing it happens in my case... .
(3) link : _http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373

---

### My Example

Here is my example : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L12phz8f/)

Problem is :

- colors are lost
- transition is not happening

I think I don't understand how transitioning is really working, I could have missed something that could help me in this case.
Any help ?

-

Listener of button call click method that redefined nodes and path.

```
/*CHANGING DATA*/
function click(d){
  d3.select("#container").selectAll("path").remove();

  var nodes = partition.nodes(d)
      .filter(function(d) {
      return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
      }) ;

  var path = vis.data([d]).selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .each(stash)
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attrTween("d", arcTween);
  ;

  // Get total size of the tree = value of root node from partition.
  totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;
}
```

_

```
 // Stash the old values for transition.
function stash(d) {
   d.x0 = d.x;
   d.dx0 = d.dx;
}
  // Interpolate the arcs in data space.
 function arcTween(a) {
   var i = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0}, a);
   return function(t) {
     var b = i(t);
     a.x0 = b.x;
     a.dx0 = b.dx;
     return arc(b);
   };
 }
```

---

Data Characteristics :

- the root node is the same for the two datasets.
- the structure is globally the same, only the values are changing.
- Some fields disappear but we can add them with value equal to 0.

---